# Grails With STS - Get EhCache?

Tags: grails, ehcache, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have an existing Grails project that I am upgrading to a new version.  When I build the project I get an error `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/jcache/JCache`

After googling, it looks like I had an outdated version of EhCache that I also need to upgrade.  I poked around but don't know the "best" way to get this version in my project and what version I should be gunning for (or how I would know).

I am running Springsource Tool Suite 2.6.1 and Grails 1.3.7.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like there is a lib in my Grails 1.3.7/lib folder that has ehcache-1.4.1.jar in it, but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I had conflicting references to EhCache in my project.  When I deleted all of them except the one in my Grails dependency it worked correctly.